# regex to find number between a number and a bracket

Tags: php, regex

I have something like

```
Page 1 of 7 (1-49 of 325)
```

I need to find the last page by using regex.

Here is what i have as regex expression

```
<?php

$page = 'Page 1 of 7 (1-49 of 325)';

$matches = array();
$t = preg_match('/of(.*?)\(/s', $page, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);


?>
```

It works fine, it outputs 7.

My problem is when ever i use

```
<?php

$page = file_get_contents('http://www.exaample.com');

$matches = array();
$t = preg_match('/of(.*?)\(/s', $page, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);


?>
```

i get a lot of text, but i dont get the output '7'.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should mark a answer as correct if you found a solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
$t = preg_match('/Page [0-9]+ of ([0-9]+)/i', $page, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this regular expression `\d+(?=\s*\()`

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$str = 'Page 1 of 7 (1-49 of 325)';
preg_match('/\([0-9]+\-([0-9]+) of [0-9]+\)/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Not tested.

Comment: Don't upvote my answer please. I just tested it, and it doesn't work :(

Comment: All fixed. Feel free to do whatever now.

Comment: You're getting the wrong number. OP wants `7` Also so many captures not needed.

Comment: Output: array(2) { [0]=> string(13) "(1-49 of 325)" [1]=> string(3) "325" }. edit: Oh for shit sakes. edit 2: There lmao.